# Make inherited members static

Tags: c++, inheritance, static-members

I have to classes, `A` and `B`, and `B` inherits members from `A` publicly.

```
class A {
public:
    int a;
};

class B : A {
};
```

Is there a way to make all of the inherited members from `A` static under `B`, or creating them `static` in `A` is the only way through?

---

**Context**:

I'm building a memory manager, and this manager would control the memory used by instances of a particular class.

I'd have something like:

```
template <class T>
class Memory {
public:
    operator new;
    operator delete;
private:
    memory_pool_for<T>;
};

class Data : Memory<Data> {
};
```

And so, when I got to do something like:

```
new Data;
delete Data;
```

The operation would be called from the function defined in `Memory`, that would allocate/deallocate some memory space.

The allocation/deallocation should be static among `Data` instances, and I'd like to be sure no extra bytes would be added to each instance of `Data` due to the inheritance from `Memory`. That's why I thought of `static`'lizing the inheritance.

I'm not sure if this is the best way to do what I'm doing, but this is quite the most elegant approach I could think of so far.

Comment: Short answer: no. You'd need to *instance* a static A inside B.

Comment: There is no such a feature in C++, and I fail to see a concrete use case that would necessarily require it. Why do you think you need it?

Comment: If you present a *real* use case, we might think of a better solution. Right now it's really unclear what you might need it for.

Comment: @AndyProwl,BartekBanachewics I've added some context to my question.

Comment: @WhozCraig Instantiate*!

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Too much rum =P

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would use composition instead of inheritance:

```
class B { 
    static A a;
};
```

Since you won't probably satisfy [LSP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle) with B anyway, if you want to make inherited members `static`.

---

Regarding context, I would just make a static protected allocators in `Memory`:

```
class Memory {
protected:
    static void* allocate();
    static void destroy (void*);
```

And use them in `new` and `delete` operators:

```
public:
    void* operator new (size_t) { return allocate(); }
    void operator delete (void* mem) { return destroy(mem); }
}
```

This way, when you inherit from `Memory`, you can use its static allocators.

Anyway, I am not sure if it's a good approach. It obviously limits you to one memory pool (but that's what you wanted to anyway, no?). If you wanted to have one memory allocator instance *per type*, just add a template tag to `Memory` and inherit with CRTP:

```
template<typename Tag> class Memory { ...

class Data : Memory<Data> {
};
```

You might want to look at how Standard Library container allocators are used, though. Being compatible with stdlib is always a nice thing.

Comment: Yep, that's one common memory pool per type. Templates look awesome (: I'll try out your suggestions. Thanks very much! 5555 Interstella! (: